# Returning a lambda function with parameter types constrained by generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, lambda, types, type-inference

Suppose that I want to write a method `buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs`, which produces a two-argument `BiFunction` whose input arguments are of the same type. It is not known ahead of time (i.e. when `buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs` is invoked) specifically what type that is -- I just want the compiler to enforce that whenever the function returned by `buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs` is invoked, the types of the arguments provided to it must match. The end effect should be, essentially, the lambda equivalent of using the same generic type parameter for the type of two arguments in a method definition.

My initial attempt looks like the following:

```
public interface ConstrainedBiFunction<I, O> extends BiFunction<I, I, O> {}

public static ConstrainedBiFunction<?, String> buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs() {
    return (inputOne, inputTwo) -> String.valueOf(inputOne) + String.valueOf(inputTwo);
}

public void test() {
    buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs().apply(Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2));
}
```

It appears, however, that the wildcard type parameter `?` cannot be used in this way; compilation fails on the `apply` step with the following error:

```
apply (capture<?>, capture<?> in BiFunction cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
```

Is it possible to return a lambda function whose parameter types are inferred, then constrained relative to one another in this way?

**EDIT:** Apologies for the not-very-good question; I had a more complex problem of which I was trying to capture the essence in order to ask the simplest-possible question here, but it looks like I simplified the problem too much. I'm aware, of course, that all classes inherit from `Object`, so in this over-simplified rendition of the problem, the solutions proposed by @shmosel and @JB Nizet work. I'll post a new question once I've done a better job distilling the original problem.

Comment: How do you think `ConstrainedBiFunction<?, String>` relates to `.apply(Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2));`?

Comment: All classes ultimately inherit from Object, so even if you pass, for example, a Banana and a Truck, the compiler will infer it as a ConstrainedBuFunction<Object, Object, String>, unless you explicitly specify the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard means "of a specific, but unknown type". You can't pass *any* argument that will satisfy a parameter of type `?`, since it may be of the wrong type. Change the return type to `ConstrainedBiFunction<Object, String>` and it will be able to accept any input type, since every class implicitly extends `Object`:

```
public static ConstrainedBiFunction<Object, String> buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs() {
    return (inputOne, inputTwo) -> String.valueOf(inputOne) + String.valueOf(inputTwo);
}
```

Note that this can still be used for methods with restrictions on the input type, using the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1553851) principle. For example:

```
// input parameter must be of type Integer or any supertype,
// so that we can safely pass in an Integer
String combine(ConstrainedBiFunction<? super Integer, String> function) {
    return function.apply(1, 2);
}

void test() {
    ConstrainedBiFunction<Object, String> concat = buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs();
    ConstrainedBiFunction<Integer, String> sum = (a, b) -> String.valueOf(a + b);
    System.out.println(combine(concat)); // "12"
    System.out.println(combine(sum));    // "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [shmosel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624634/2711488) correctly points out that using `Object` as input type should be sufficient for all APIs following the PECS rule, it is possible to fix your original attempt.

Instead of a wildcard, you have to add a type parameter which allows the caller to choose a type:

```
public interface ConstrainedBiFunction<I, O> extends BiFunction<I, I, O> {}

public static <T> ConstrainedBiFunction<T, String> buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs() {
    return (inputOne, inputTwo) -> String.valueOf(inputOne) + String.valueOf(inputTwo);
}

public void test() {
    ConstrainedBiFunction<Integer, String> f1 = buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs();
    String s1 = f1.apply(1, 1);
    ConstrainedBiFunction<String, String>  f2 = buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs();
    String s2 = f2.apply("hello ", "world");
}
```

Note that when using it as `buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs().apply(1, 1);`, the compiler will infer `Object` for `T` anyway. This allow to pass `Integer` arguments, but, of course, also anything else, which makes the idea of having the same type for both arguments moot, i.e. `buildBiFxnWithSameTypeArgs().apply(1.5, "foo");` works as well, as both arguments are assignable to the same type `Object`.

---

There are some real life examples for such constructs dealing with problems not solvable via PECS.

E.g. there is [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) returning an arbitrary typed function having the same input and output type. When passing this function to the [`toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), you can get a map having the same key or value type as the stream elements.

A more complex example is [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--). Here, the type parameter has a bound that ensures that the elements to compare are indeed `Comparable`. Since the types don’t implement `Comparable<?>`, but rather a type referring to itself, the `naturalOrder()` wouldn’t work without the type parameter.

So you can’t do `Comparator.naturalOrder().compare(42, "foo")`. But you can do

```
Comparator<Integer> c1 = Comparator.naturalOrder();
c1.compare(10, 42);
Comparator<String> c2  = Comparator.naturalOrder();
c2.compare("foo", "bar");
```